# CakePhp 3.x non-default view file extension

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

**I moved from CakePhp 2.x to CakePhp 3.x**

In CakePhp 2.x, in my ApiController I could do something like this:

```
public function getScript(){
    $this->layout = 'empty';
    $this->ext = '.js';
}
```

**The above code would have rendered the following view:**

View/Api/get_script.js
(please note the .js extension)

**How can I implement the same behaviour using CakePhp 3.x?**

I read in the documentation that:

> The Controller::$ext property has been removed. You now have to extend and override the View::$_ext property if you want to use a non-default view file extension.

But I don't understand how and where to extend the View::$_ext property

**I tried the following:**

I created a new View class in **src/View/ApiView.php**

```
namespace App\View;

use Cake\View\View;

class ApiView extends View
{
    protected $_ext = '.js';    
}
```

And in my controller:

```
public function getScript(){

        $this->viewClass='Api';
        $this->layout = 'ajax';


    }
```

But now I get the following error :

> Error: The layout file Layout/ajax.js can not be found or does not
>   exist.

And this makes perfect sense since I told CakePhp to use .js as the default extension. But I would like to use the .ctp extension for the layout and the .js extension for the template view.

It was so simple in CakePHP 2.x I believe there must be an easy solution in CakePHP3.x too.. please help!

Thank you

Comment: it means by creating `WhateverView` - and using that class.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do.. but I can't override the _ext property (It doesn't work), I need some sample code

Comment: If you have some sample code put it in the question - it seems unlikely you're doing what the instructions suggest.

Comment: I tried different things.. I've edited the question and added the code that has given the closest solution so far. But still I'm not getting what I'd like..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using template extensions you might want to look at using RequestHandlerComponent to do content-type negotiation. This would let you use directories like `Template/Api/js/action.ctp`. I find this helps keep the various response formats for an API clean as controllers with many actions don't end up with sprawling list of view files.

To answer your original question, you can't change the extension for only the template, and not the layout with the default view class. You would need a custom view class if you want that kind of behavior. Take a look at [_getViewFileName](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/View/View.php#L871) and [_getLayoutFileName](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/View/View.php#L968) for which methods to override in a subclass.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have your cake and eat it (too)! The `$_ext` property is being used for all template types (actions, elements, layouts), and its usage is buried in various different places, so changing this to be used selectively is a little tedious.

Your best bet would probably be to override `View::_getViewFileName()` and change the extension temporarily, that's not very nice, but the least intrusive solution that comes to my mind right now:

```
protected function _getViewFileName($name = null)
{
    $oldExt = $this->_ext;
    $this->_ext = '.js';
    $filename = parent::_getViewFileName($name);
    $this->_ext = $oldExt;
    return $filename;
}
```